# ActiveX control property not working (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, activex

I have a C# ActiveX control with an interface defined akin to:

```
int MyInt { get; set; }
string MyString { get; set; }
Color MyColor { get; set; }
```

The interface is implemented as follows:

```
protected int myInternalInt;
protected string myInternalString;
protected Color myInternalColor;
public int MyInt { get { return myInternalInt; } set { myInternalInt = value; } }
public string MyString { get { return myInternalString; } set { myInternalString = value; } }
public Color MyColor { get { return myInternalColor; } set { myInternalColor = value; } }
```

The int and string properties (and other basic types I've tried) work as expected but the Color type does not.  The control's property page correctly interprets the type and populates a dropdown for selection of a Color type.  However, it does not display the current internal value of the Color-type property (showing Black instead, i.e., default) nor does it pass back any changes made by the user.  The same still holds true if myInternalColor is explicitly initialized above, such as "protected Color myInternalColor = Color.Blue;".

Can anyone shed some light on how to make the Color property work, i.e., pass its value in and out of the control correctly?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

It now appears to me the issue I outlined above may be a COM Interop problem.  It turns out the UserControl TestContainer within my VS2008 development environment seemingly interacts with the Color properties correctly, but the ActiveX Control Test Container provided with VS6 does not.  The actual container in which the control is designed to run is COM-based and I'm betting the aforementioned Ax test container is as well.

(And being new to User Controls development, it looks like I failed to understand that the WinForm control I'm developing is technically not an ActiveX control, a distinction that I've only come to know through recent research.)

Comment: This code looks fine. The problem could be in your binding code that binds the color property to the relevant control (a dropdown?). Can you post that code?

Comment: By "dropdown" I'm referring to the standard Windows color selection dialog, which comes up in this upon clicking the property's dropdown arrow in the property sheet.

Comment: I hit enter by mistake, so to continue... The binding is presumably being handled by Visual Studio or .Net automatically; I don't have visibility into anything that looks like binding code.